# ExactTarget HubExchange Application Event Callbacks

Tags: marketing-cloud, app

We've built a HubExchange app and are almost ready to submit it for approval. It's working fine in the sandbox environment; we've created the HubExchange app in https://appcenter.exacttargetapps.com and I've defined all the Application Endpoints which work fine with the ET SSO/JWT integration. However, I see there are also three callback URLs which we also need to define:

### Application Event Callbacks

- **Install URL** (This endpoint identifies the location from which the user can perform an installation of the app inside their IMH account.)
- **Uninstall URL** (This endpoint identifies the location from which the user can uninstall the app from their IMH account.)
- **Access Approved URL** (This endpoint identifies the location ExactTarget notifies when the user accepts the data ccess requested by the app.)

It's not clear from these descriptions what these endpoint URLs need to be, that is, do they refer to a URL within the App, or are these URLs on hubexchange.exacttarget.com which are defined once our app is certified? I can't find any documentation related to this. If anyone can share some insight, I would greatly appreciate it.

Comment: Those are related to the HubExchange marketplace itself and how people are able to provision your application for them within that interface using these endpoints.

Answer (score 1):

Those URLs are to provide your application with "provisioning" information for HubExchange.

They aren't required "up-front" during development, but during the "certification process", you will be asked to provide the necessary functionality for those endpoints to ensure a smooth on-boarding process for ExactTarget customers who decide to use your HubExchange application.

Comment: Is there any documentation anywhere for their protocol?