# Implementing Marketing Cloud HubExchange Application Event Callbacks

Tags: marketing-cloud, hubexchange, appcenter

this is an extension from my original question regarding [HubExchange Application Event Callbacks](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/41262/exacttarget-hubexchange-application-event-callbacks).

We've created a HubExchange app and its been through the certification process but I'm now looking at implementing the **Install URL** Application Event Callback. Essentially what I want to do is to send an email to a user once they "install" our app from HubExchange like here:

[image: installing app]

I'm assuming that's what this callback is for, that is when the app is installed by a user in HubExchange, an HTTP request is made to the the Install URL that I've defined in AppCenter, which I guess is essentially a webhook. Is assumption is correct, would this be a POST request and what values are passed to the Install URL?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I hate bringing bad news, but the call back URL is not operational, and currently serves no purpose.

I have the product manager looking into how to get that corrected, until then, no dice.

Comment: So that explains why it doesn't work then! What a misleading feature. Please can you request that it's disabled from the UI until it actually does something? I wouldn't want other developers to spend a heap of hours (like I have done) trying to find out what they are "doing wrong" when it doesn't actually work :-(

Answer (score 2):

In a discussion I had with an ExactTarget product manager and engineer,  they told me that the Callbacks don't work and that I should ignore those settings.

I had the same assumptions you did and performed some initial experiments and found that those callback URL's did nothing.

I'd love to hear if you could get them to work.

Comment: As a side note... did you get OAuth refresh to work using the refreshToken provided via the JWT?

Comment: How odd. I will reach out the the HubExchange team to find out if this is the case (and if so I will award you the bounty). OAuth is working fine for us with JWT — we ended up using the [Fuel Node Auth](https://github.com/ExactTarget/Fuel-Node-Auth) authentication library for managing access tokens so we don't need to keep track of expired tokens.

Comment: And this works for installs on other sites (besides the site you developed on)? We found the FuelSDK (for us, C#) didn't really handle the HubExchange use case as the refresh done by the SDK doesn't take into account contextualized tokens.

Comment: Interesting, I haven't experienced this. If the SDK isn't working for you, then you could always manage token refresh yourself by keeping track of when a token expires and use the `refreshToken` parameter in the payload when it's time to get a new contextualized token.

Comment: Forget everything I said about the refreshToken. Too much turkey and red wine still in my system. I was using the wrong clientID and client secret. I am doing my own token management and got my configs messed up :P

Comment: Its possible the C# sdk doesn't manage refresh tokens, but i don't write in c# so I'm not sure. I can have some one take a look.